# Convert a completely random XML to HTML with a completely generic XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Various questions on the XML to HTML conversion topic using XSLT are already dealt with here. But I haven't come across an XSLT template with which the following can be achieved:

- The setup of the XML is completely random, i.e.

  - the element names can have whatever names
  - the elements can be randomly arranged
  - the XML can but need not be nested
  - nested elements can include other nested elements to whatever
    hierarchy level
  - it can be a random number of elements

See the following HTML example with 3 HTML tables for visualizing what should be achieved.

- An XML can be fairly simple, not containing any nested elements. Empty cell content should indeed be reflected. "a" and all other elements may have whatever names.
- XML with nested elements. This may be another table that itself can have nested elements (as in the third example) or it's just flat. It can have whatever content. For example, the column "g" can also have tables ("j" and "m" could be tables as well with whatever number of table rows).

So, the XSLT should be completely generic to handle completely random content that should be converted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>e</th>
                        <th>f</th>
                        <th>g</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>h</td>
                        <td>i</td>
                        <td>j</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>k</td>
                        <td>l</td>
                        <td>m</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>n</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>b</th>
                        <th>c</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>d</td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>e</th>
                                    <th>f</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>g</td>
                                    <td>h</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So in your world any XML to HTML conversion creates some nested tables? Well, what have you tried to implement? Where is the XML input that is to be transformed to the HTML tables you have shown?

Comment: How would you determine that a section in "a completely random" XML needs to be transformed to a table? The XML format is *much* more flexible than that. The only thing you can say to describe it in general is that it's a tree. To represent *any* tree in HTML, you should use nested lists, not tables. And that's not too difficult to implement in XSLT.

Comment: You need to put a lot more effort into specifying the requirements. At one level it's trivial: just output HTML that contains the serialized XML as the text of a paragraph. That's not what you want, I suspect. But you haven't come anywhere near to specifying what you DO want.